# iOS swift: Unrecognised selector sent to instance

Tags: facebook, sdk

I'm trying to integrate the latest Facebook SDK to my iOS swift code. When I update the login button to my custom view I'm getting:

> "**UIView setReadPermissions:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**".

This is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var fbLoginView: FBSDKLoginButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil)
    {
        println("Not logged in..")
    }
    else
    {
        println("Logged in..")
    }

    self.fbLoginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
    self.fbLoginView.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: The problem appears to be in the readPermissins function call. You should make sure that "public_profile", "email", "user_friends" are all typed correctly and can be found. Also, make sure the IBOutlet is connect properly.

Comment: Which version of the Facebook SDK are you using?